# Use ASP.NET Core Web API with an app that's not using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Is it possible to use Web API within a .NET Core application that is not using MVC, but making use of app.Run?

I want to provide a simple API and would rather use Web API than roll my own. I've added in MvcCore in `ConfigureServices`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddMvcCore(x =>
        {
            x.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        }).AddFormatterMappings()
        .AddJsonFormatters();

        // ...
    }
```

I added a very simple Controller:

```
[Route("/api/test")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return Ok("Hello World");
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to hit /api/test my normal processing code within App.Run processes.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var scopeFactory = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

        // ...

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var request = new Request(context);
                var response = new Response(context);

                await scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestFactory>().ProcessAsync(request, response);
            }
        });
    }
```

How do I defer to the Web API if I don't want to handle the request?

Comment: Look up app.Map()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to configure MVC,you have to add it both in ConfigureServices and Configure like below

**ConfigureServices**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {      
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

**Configure**

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

So in your code,you have only done the first part.

> Also I see that you have used **app.Run** ,do not use Run if you have
>   other middlewares to run.app.Run delegate terminates the pipeline and MVC middleware will not get chance to execute

What you have to do is to change the code to app.Map ,refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) for the user of Run,use and map

So the order of middleware matters. you have to change the code like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        var scopeFactory = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

        // ...

        app.Use(async (context,next) =>
        {
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var request = new Request(context);
                var response = new Response(context);

                await scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestFactory>().ProcessAsync(request, response);
            }
          await next.Invoke()

        });
       app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic, all I needed to add was app.UseMvc. Thanks for your help.